# Sections with different scrolling directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve A very cool effect I found in this website:

https://platforma.ws/

as you can see, at the very end the scrolling changes of direction, instead of scrolling to the bottom it starts scrolling to the right side.

I want to do something similar, but after completing the scrolling to the right side I would like to continue the down scrolling for a while. Like this image attached[image: example here]

Can someone recommend me a method to achieve this? is this possible only using html/css? or will require some javascript?

thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling

Comment: Also, please see [this other question that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607685/changing-scroll-direction-from-vertical-to-horizontal-on-the-same-page/) I have already answered on SO that is **very** similar to your question.