# HTML A way to infinitely scroll text in a square around page using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I already have a horizontal infinite scroll of text in my header, but I want it to wrap around in a square pattern around the page. How would someone go about doing this?

Here's my code:

```
.marquee {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee2 span {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}


<h1 class="marquee">
         <span>Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan
Urbiel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
     </h1>

     <h1 class="marquee marquee2">
         <span>Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan
Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
     </h1>
```

I was thinking of an animation such as this:

```
    div {
       height: 400px;
       width:500px;
       border: solid 1px blue;
       position: relative;
    }
    h3 {
        background-color: tomato;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        animation: move 5s infinite linear;
        position: absolute;
    }


    @keyframes move {
        0% { left: 0px; top: 0%; transform: translate(-0%, 0%);}
       25% { left: 0px; top: 100%; transform: translate(0%, -100%);}
       50% { left: 100%; top: 100%; transform: translate(-100%, -100%);}
       75% { left: 100%; top: 0%; transform: translate(-100%, -0%);}
       100% { left: 0px; top: 0%; transform: translate(-0%, 0%);}
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div>
      <h3>Hai</h3>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

But, instead of the text remaining horizontal all the way through each direction change, I'd like the text to change horizontally or vertically depending on the direction the text is going.

Comment: Could you supply a bit more detail on what is meant by _but I want it to wrap around in a square pattern around the page._? Thanks

Comment: Yes, apologies about the original description.

Comment: Thanks, just chuck in whatever CSS/HTML you've tried to make it square & a graphical description of what you're after.

Comment: I mean I would like text to infinitely scroll around the borders of the webpage, with text going from horizontal scrolling to vertical scrolling once it hits a certain point on the page.

Comment: You'll need to implement an automatic version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50609140/11700321) with the `scrollbar` element `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're talking about? You'll have to figure out how to alter it to fit your needs, but the words are circling the border.

The two caveats with the way I did it are:

1. The square element is necessary to get the rectangular one to align properly when rotated
2. Because the words extend past the square element, they go out of bounds which is why I set the wrapper to hide overflow.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width:500px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.move-around {
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: moveAround 5s infinite linear;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.change-direction {
  background-color: #ccf4;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: changeDirection 5s infinite steps(1, end);
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
}

@keyframes moveAround {
    0% { left: 0px; top: 0%; transform: translate(0%, 0%);}
   25% { left: 0px; top: 100%; transform: translate(0%, -100%);}
   50% { left: 100%; top: 100%; transform: translate(-100%, -100%);}
   75% { left: 100%; top: 0%; transform: translate(-100%, 0%);}
  100% { left: 0px; top: 0%; transform: translate(0%, 0%);}
}

@keyframes changeDirection {
    0% { transform: rotate(90deg); }
   25% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
   50% { transform: rotate(270deg); }
   75% { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="move-around">
    <div class="change-direction">
      <h3>Hello There!</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do get the feeling you meant a ticker border though. In which case, you could maybe just do what you already figured out, except 4 times for each side of the element.

The issue here is figuring out what to do at the corners when they overlap. Beats me! Maybe it will look good if you have colored boxes covering the corners?

```css
.marquee {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.marquee.bottom {
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.marquee.left {
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(-50% + 0.5em);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.marquee.right {
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  top: 50%;
  right: calc(-50% + 0.5em);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.marquee > .part {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee > .part.two {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="marquee top">
  <span class="part one">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
  <span class="part two">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
</h1>

<h1 class="marquee bottom">
  <span class="part one">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
  <span class="part two">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
</h1>

<h1 class="marquee left">
  <span class="part one">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
  <span class="part two">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
</h1>

<h1 class="marquee right">
  <span class="part one">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
  <span class="part two">
    Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stan Urbiel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
</h1>
```