# Restricting scroll direction from vertical/horizontal within same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish the same switch from vertical to horizontal scrolling seen
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607685/changing-scroll-direction-from-vertical-to-horizontal-on-the-same-page).

However, scrolling on the horizontal section while both sections are in view will enable horizontal scrolling. Is there a way to enable horizontal scrolling & restrict vertical scrolling only when the vertical section is not visible? Apologies for the awkward wording; essentially, I'd like the red portion to only be scrolled to when the white portion is already out of view.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop >= 1000){
      $("html, body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
          this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
          $("html,body").toggleClass("disable-scroll");
       });
    }
});
```

```css
#outsidescrollwrapper{
 width: 100vh;
 height: 100vw;
 transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
 transform-origin: top left;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
.sidescrollwrapper{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 200vw;
 transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
 transform-origin: top left;
}
.sidescrollwrapper > .sidescroll {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
#about{
  height: 1000px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FBFDFF, white);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about">
</div>
<div id="outsidescrollwrapper">
 <div class="sidescrollwrapper">
  <div style="background-color:blue" class="sidescroll"></div>
  <div style="background-color:red" class="sidescroll"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1h4yeac0/

Comment: Just to recap and see if I understand correctly. There are (at least) 2 sections. Default scroll behavior is vertical. Whenever the first section is completely out of view and the second section is in the view change the scroll behavior to a horizontal direction. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, exactly - that'd be my intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this snippet below which observes elements that use a `data-direction` attribute. The values on these attributes can be whatever you want, but I chose to give them either `horizontal` or `vertical` value, which could be the scroll directions which you can use.

This will only monitor the elements that you query with the `selector` argument and will **not** change the direction of scrolling. That part I leave up to you to handle.

The `callback` will trigger whenever there is only **1** of the *observerd* elements in the viewport (which is what you requested, I believe). That callback has a parameter which is the current direction value. Based on that value you can switch your scroll directions.

I hope this helps you out, man.

```js
/**
 * Observes elements that indicate the current 
 * scroll-direction based on a data-direction attribute.
 * The callbacks fires with the current direction whenever 
 * a single observed element is in view.
 *
 * @param {string} selector
 * @param {function} callback
 * @returns {IntersectionObserver}
 */
function directionObserver(selector, callback) {

  /**
   * Store elements that are in view in a Set and 
   * set the default direction.
   */
  const elementsInView = new Set();
  let currentDirection = 'vertical';

  /**
   * Callback that runs whenever observed
   * elements intersect.
   *
   * @param {IntersectionObserverEntry[]} entries
   */
  const intersectionCallback = entries => {

    /**
     * Check if current entries are in view.
     * If they are add them to the elementsInView array
     * and remove them if they are not.
     */
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      const { target } = entry;
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        elementsInView.add(target);
      } else {
        elementsInView.delete(target);
      }
    });

    /**
     * Whenever there is only one element in the view
     * switch the currentDirection to the value of the
     * direction data attribute.
     */
    if (elementsInView.size === 1) {
      for (const element of elementsInView.values()) {
        currentDirection = element.dataset.direction;
        if ('function' === typeof callback) {
          callback(currentDirection);
        }
      }
    }

  }

  /**
   * Options for the observer
   */
  const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '50px 0px',
    threshold: [0, 1]
  };

  /**
   * Create observer
   */
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback, options);

  /**
   * Observer elements based on the selector argument
   */
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  sections.forEach(section => observer.observe(section));
  
  return currentDirection;
  
}

// Use the observer and observe all the .section elements.
directionObserver('.section', direction => {
  console.log(`Current direction is: ${direction}`);
  // Change scroll direction based on direction value.
});
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.vertical {
  width: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    0deg, 
    white, 
    white 50px, 
    red 50px, 
    red 100px
   );
}

.horizontal {
  width: 300vw;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    90deg, 
    white, 
    white 50px, 
    blue 50px, 
    blue 100px
   );
}
```

```html
<div class="section vertical" data-direction="vertical"></div>
<div class="section horizontal" data-direction="horizontal"></div>
```